# DrawerLayout Pressing Back on Top Level Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having Navigation Drawer implemented with Drawer Layout. I am using FragmentTransaction replace when an item is chosen.

Assuming Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment3 are all Top Level Fragments selectable in Drawer, when I select one Fragment after other, the previous one is added the stack and comes up when I press back button.

So if I click in this order:
Fragment1->Fragment2->Fragment3->Fragment2->Fragment3

On pressing back it goes back in stack like this:
Fragment3->Fragment2->Fragment3->Fragment2->Fragment1->Exit

Instead I want the app to exit when back is pressed when on any of the top level fragments.

Sounds simple enough, but I can't seem to figure out. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you wanna get rid of the backstack behavior, so don't add the Fragments to the backstack using `addToBackstack(null)` like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.your_container,  
        yourFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit;
```

Comment: Yes, removing addToBackStack(null) helped. Thanks!